# Mysql Query date >= 90 days

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to query a database for records where the date is equal to, or greater than 90 days.
This is what I have so far:

```
$format = 'Y-m-j G:i:s'; 

$date = date ( $format ); 

// -90 days from today 

date ( $format, strtotime ( '-90 day' . $date ) );
```

I'm just a bit unsure now how to structure the MYSQL query. Would it be *something* like this (I know this is wrong but i'm unsure as to what else to do):

```
"SELECT * FROM recurringPayments WHERE lastpmt >= date ( $format, strtotime ( '-90 day' . $date ) ) ";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
$d = date ( $format, strtotime ( '-90 days' ) );

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recurringPayments WHERE lastpmt <= '$d'");
?>
```

Assuming you want data 90 days and older.

Answer (score 32):

```
<?php
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recurringPayments WHERE lastpmt <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY)");
?>
```

Comment: Agree with doing it in SQL.  Although it's minimal overhead in creating the new var in PHP and invoking a function, it is still more overhead relative to doing the date math within the query.

Comment: If you need the output as a timestamp or need to compare against a timestamp, wrap the date math within UNIX_TIMESTAMP.  In this example, if you wanted timestamp output, the query would be mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recurringPayments WHERE lastpmt <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY))");