# How can i check the input date is with in last 90 days or not in php

Tags: php

I am using jquery date picker and from that i got the date as a format of yyyy-mm-dd.
what i need to know that, i want to check the input date is in last 90 days or not from today.

```
$( "#dt_affected" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
});
```

and i read it in php as
`$posted["dt_affected"]= $this->input->post("dt_affected", true);`
and i got the result `2011-06-15`
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906361/mysql-query-date-90-days

Comment: Where is your code ? You tagged jQuery & JS , why ?

Comment: for date picker i use this
$( "#dt_salary_affected" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
    });

and i read it in my php 
$posted["dt_salary_affected"]           = $this->input->post("dt_salary_affected", true); 

i got the result as 2011-06-15.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check date on server side the you can use the following code

```
echo date ( $format, strtotime ( '-90 day' . $date ) );
```

Comment: i want to check according to the date that i got from the date picker.
if that date is with in the last 90 days from today then i will do something else something.